# How do I get the source element in the AjaxOptions OnComplete function with MVC Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, callback, parameter-passing

As the title, I need something along the lines of...

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction",
                        new AjaxOptions {
                            OnComplete = "function() { mySucessFunction(this); }"
                        }))


<script>
    function mySucessFunction(srcElem) {
        alert(srcElem.id);
    }
</script>
```

Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", 
                       new AjaxOptions { OnFailure = "Ajaxerror",
                                         OnBegin="helper_xmlRequestFormControl" ,
                                         OnComplete = "helper_xmlRequestFormSaveEnd", 
                                         UpdateTargetId = "form_customer_create" 
                                        }))       
       { .........   %> 


   <script >
    function helper_xmlRequestFormSaveEnd(obj) {

        //obj.get_data() => server response data 
        //obj.get_request() => ajax object
        //obj.get_loadingElement()=> loading elementId 
        //obj.get_updateTarget()=>updateTarget
        //obj.get_response() => Sys.Mvc.AjaxContext

    }
  </script>
```